# Prove that $A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[G]} B = (A \otimes B)_G$

Tags: homological-algebra

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$
This identity occurs in Cassels and Frohlich, page 98. Let me recall the context: If $A, B$ are left $G$--module i.e. $\Z[G]$-module then we turn $A$ into right $G$-module by defining $a \cdot g = g^{-1} a$ so that tensor product $A \otimes_{\Z[G]} B$ makes sense. For any $G$-module $A$, we define
$$A_G = \Z \otimes_{\Z[G]} A = A/I_G A$$
where $I_G$ is the augmentation ideal, generated by $g - 1$ for all $g \not= 1$. This is largest quotient of $A$ where $G$ acts identically. (Here, $\Z$ is a $(\Z[G], \Z[G])$-bimodule with trivial action on both sides.) The equation in question also reads
$$A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[G]} B = \Z \otimes_{\Z[G]} (A \otimes B)$$
Note that the defined right action does NOT make $A$ into a $(\Z[G], \Z[G])$-bimodule since the associativity $g (a h) = (g a) h$ does not hold in general. So I do not expect the LHS to be a well-behaved $\Z[G]$-module with obvious action $g(a \otimes b) = ga \otimes b$. The obvious correspondence $a \otimes b \mapsto 1 \otimes (a \otimes b)$ does not seem to work: $g (a \otimes b) = ga \otimes b \mapsto 1 \otimes (ga \otimes b)$ and $g (1 \otimes (a \otimes b)) = 1 \otimes (a \otimes b)$ and one do not expect $ga \otimes b = a \otimes b$ in $A \otimes B$.

**EDIT**: I think I get this now. We always define $G$-action on $A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[G]} B$ and $A \otimes B$ to be
$$g(a \otimes b) = ga \otimes gb,$$
not the one I expected from general tensor product $M \otimes_R N$ where $M$ is $(S,R)$-bimodule.

Comment: We usually only define the action on tensor products via the diagonal when tensoring over the base ring. Note that you do need the defined action to even take tensor products over the group algebra.

Comment: Also note that the action on the tensor product over the group algebra is trivial if you use the diagonal.